# reccomending, according to the selected listbox value

Tags: python, tkinter

the code is a bit long, hope you understand it, i have this small app, where i have to implement data from 2 files, and then showing some of the values(of data) in list box. on the other side i have combined the values in nested dictionary. Now i have to recommend movie according the the value i will select from list box. Maybe the code i have written is wrong in some parts, though in the last part, when i have to write the code of recommendation, i have no clue how i have to write the code, i so it will recommend me movie, for further explanation, i will be writing in comments part if needed.     (Data&recommendations file: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b949hapk5lmm94i/AAD29ykbvWq83wZbFpvvqw69a?dl=0)

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
import csv
from recommendations import *
class STproject:

def __init__(self): #1

    self.variableclasses()
    self.buttonsnlabels()
    self.dictionary()


def variableclasses(self):
    self.all_vars = [StringVar() for _ in range(2)]
    self.var1 = StringVar()
    self.var2 = StringVar()

    self.var1.set(0)
    self.var2.set(0)

def buttonsnlabels(self):

    self.rdbttn=Radiobutton(root,text='user based recommendation',variable = self.var1,value=1,command=lambda:self.dictionary())#, command=lambda :self.selec1())
    self.rdbttn.grid(row=0,column=0)
    self.rdbttn2=Radiobutton(root,text='movie based recommendation',variable = self.var1,value=2,command=lambda:self.dictionary())#,command=lambda :self.selec1())
    self.rdbttn2.grid(row=1,column=0)
    self.rdbttn3=Radiobutton(root,text='pearson',variable = self.var2,value=1)#,command=lambda :self.selec2())
    self.rdbttn3.grid(row=2,column=0)
    self.rdbttn4=Radiobutton(root,text='euclidean',variable = self.var2,value=2)#,command=lambda :self.selec2())
    self.rdbttn4.grid(row=3,column=0)

    self.ratingbutton=Button(root,text='Upload Rating',command=lambda :self.file(self.all_vars[0]))
    self.ratingbutton.grid()
    self.ratingbutton=Button(root,text='Upload Movies',command=lambda :self.file(self.all_vars[1]))
    self.ratingbutton.grid()

    self.lb1 = Listbox(root)
    self.lb1.grid(row=0,column=1)
    self.lb2 = Listbox(root)
    self.lb2.grid(row=0,column=1)
    self.lb3 = Listbox(root)
    self.lb3.grid(row=0,column=1)

def file(self, v):
    result = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    if result:
        v.set(result)
    # self.dictionary()

def dictionary(self):
    # self.lb1.delete(END, 0)  #clear listbox
    # self.lb1.update_idletasks()
    if self.var1.get()==1:
        self.d = {}
        if all(i.get() for i in self.all_vars): #process only if all 2 files are selected
            with open(self.all_vars[0].get(),"r") as a, open(self.all_vars[1].get(),"r") as b:
                for line1,line2,line3 in zip(csv.reader(a),csv.reader(b),csv.reader(a)):
                    self.d[line1[0]]={line2[1]:line3[2]}
                    self.lb1.insert('end',line2[1])
                print self.d

    else:
        self.d = {}
        if all(i.get() for i in self.all_vars): #process only if all 2 files are selected
            with open(self.all_vars[0].get(),"r") as a, open(self.all_vars[1].get(),"r") as b:
                for line1,line2,line3 in zip(csv.reader(a),csv.reader(b),csv.reader(a)):
                    self.d[line1[0]]={line2[1]:line3[2]}
                    self.lb1.insert('end', line1[1])
                print self.d

def recoms(self):
    # selection=self.lb1.curselection()
    # print selection
    if self.var2.get()==1:
        getRecommendations()
    else:
        pass
root=Tk()
root.title('SteelBox Inc. Calculator')
application=STproject() #2
root.mainloop() #3
```

Comment: you should rather run function which gives result which you could display `results = getRecommendations(arguments)`

Comment: @furas the arguments should be (application.dictionary(),application.(selected value [which i have to create a method for it]) right?. If i am right, i fail to recall/get/print the value selected in the listbox. :(.

Comment: @furas, in which later according the selected value from listbox, it has to iterate the dictionary, and select the movie which match with that one, (if userbased [it will be according to the ratings that that user has given to the selected movie], if movie based, it will be according to the genre of that movie.).